# How do I validate a form select input value against DB with Ajax before submit the entire form to DB as insert?

Tags: jquery, nested-forms

i have a master `form` which will be inserted into `mysql`, within this form I have a select option, the user can select i.e. a Room and while select this room he can click on a button to check against the DB if this room is available.

Now the structure is kind of a nested form so far, I know, this is normally not suggested / allowed but is there another way of doing it?

All elements are suppose to be a part of the master form.

I have posted my code example below.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#checkRoom", function() {
  var data = $('#checkRoomForm').serialize();
  $.post('urlToMyPHP', data).success: function(response) {
    // on success..
    $('#checkRoomResult').val(response); // show result
  };
});

$(document).on("click", "#MasterSubmit", function() {
  var data = $('#masterForm').serialize();
  $.post('urlToMyPHP', data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="masterForm">

  <label>Name:</label>
  <input id="checkName" name="checkName">


  <form id="checkRoomForm">
    <label>Room:</label>
    <select id="selectRoom" name="selectRoom">
    <optgroup>
      <option value="R1">Room 1</option>
      <option value="R2">Room 2</option>
      <option value="R3">Room 3</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Check Room" id="checkRoom">
  </form>

  <label>Status:</label>
  <input id="checkRoomResult" value="">

<input id="MasterSubmit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your inner form to division like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="masterForm">

  <label>Name:</label>
  <input id="checkName" name="checkName">


  <div id="checkRoomForm" name="checkRoomForm">
    <label>Room:</label>
    <select id="selectRoom" name="selectRoom">
    <optgroup>
      <option value="R1">Room 1</option>
      <option value="R2">Room 2</option>
      <option value="R3">Room 3</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

    <input type="button" value="Check Room" id="checkRoom">
  </div>

  <label>Status:</label>
  <input id="checkRoomResult" value="">

<input id="MasterSubmit" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And access input data from division example here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#checkRoom").click(function(){
    console.log($("#checkRoomForm :input").serialize());
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks interesting, i'll gonna check it out.